# Вопрос к слову «всё»

Tags: части-речи, члены-предложения, частица

*Всё мрачней и ниже тучи опускаются над морем.*
Какой вопрос можно задать к слову «всё»?

Answer (score 1):

***Всё** мрачней и ниже тучи опускаются над морем...*

В этом предложении *всё* является усилительной частицей.
Частица – это служебная часть речи, вносящая различные оттенки значения в сообщение, вопросы к ней не задаются (не ставятся); членом предложения не является.

[Всё](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91)
**II. частица** (со словами, обозначающим изменяющийся признак). Указывает на нарастание или устойчивость признака. ***Шум всё сильней.** Больной всё слабеет. На улице всё так же холодно. Она всё такая же.*

Алёша шёл, и огромное водное полотно справа, стоящее от переполненности горкой "перелистывало" цвета: только что было оранжевым и бликующим, играющим с зарёй, затем фиолетовым, кладущим длинные мутные тени, затем изумрудным, с самоцветными вспышками, и становилось **всё** глубже, **всё** ярче. [В. Г. Распутин. Новая профессия (1998)]

[Что такое частица в русском языке?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/chastitsa/v-russkom-yazyke.html)

**Дополнение**
Полное предложение выглядит так:
Все мрачней и ниже тучи опускаются над морем, и поют, и рвутся волны к высоте навстречу грому (М. Горький. [Песня о Буревестнике](https://books.google.ee/books?id=9HKxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT2&lpg=PT2&dq=%D0%92%D1%81%D1%91%20%D0%BC%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC.&source=bl&ots=-idppEDuHv&sig=ACfU3U06qk-DgqnGkGSkLKHoY1i92rNflg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixq_Tm-oX0AhXk-SoKHfU_B_MQ6AF6BAgdEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D1%81%D1%91%20%D0%BC%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC.&f=false)).
При неполном цитировании в конце предложения ставится многоточие.